# Getting "firebase.functions(app)" arg expects a FirebaseApp instance or undefined in React-Native Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I am triggering an httpscallable function in GoogleCloud but receiving this error back which I could not find anywhere in documentation what is it:

> **"firebase.functions(app)" arg expects a FirebaseApp instance or undefined.**
>
> **Ensure the arg provided is a Firebase app instance; or no args to use**
>   **the default Firebase app**.

Here is my code in RN app:

```
   import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/functions'; 
   ...
    try {
        await firebase.functions('europe-west1').httpsCallable('createUserTest')();
    }
    catch (httpsError) {
        console.log(httpsError.message);
    }
```

And my Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUserTest = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const callerUid = context.auth.uid;
        const callerUserRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(callerUid);
        return { result: callerUserRecord.customClaims };
    } catch (error) {
        return { error: error };
    }
});
```

I am using this function for testing purposes just to see if I can receive back the current user custom claims or not, however, its returning that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the provided client API correctly.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation](http://@react-native-firebase/functions), especially example 3.  You'll want to do this instead:

```
const defaultApp = firebase.app();
const functionsForRegion = defaultApp.functions('europe-west1');
await functionsForRegion.httpsCallable("createUserTest")()
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! Many thanks! The documentation in the link you sent states that as you said but in this link [https://rnfirebase.io/functions/writing-deploying-functions#calling-your-function] is different. Soo confusing !

Comment: however, I still receive an error: `Error on register patient:  [Error: UNAUTHENTICATED]` even though I am authenticated and I can print my uID in the client side.

Comment: That sounds like a whole different problem.

Comment: I just made a post about that problem. If you have some time please take a look.